# fibonacci! if goes false all time

Tags: c, fibonacci

I made a program to find if a number belongs to fibonacci series or not and if it does whats its position.Whenever i type a number the if Condition goes wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main(void)
{
    int i,x=1,y=1,z,num;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a number to find in fibonacci series:");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    /*to find if the number is a part of fibonacci series or not*/
    if((isdigit(sqrt(5*num*num+4)))||(isdigit(sqrt(5*num*num-4))))  //<-- this if!
    {//belongs to fibo!
        for(i=1;    ;i++)
        {
            if(x==num)
            break;
            z=x+y;
            x=y;
            y=z;
        }
        printf("%d is the %d term of fibonacci series.",num,i);
    }
    else
        printf("Dear user,The entered number is not a part of the fibonacci series.");

    getch();
}
```

Comment: isdigit checks to see if the given char is a valid ascii digit, 0-9. I've no idea what you are trying to use it for. You also really need to put an upper bound on your for loop.

Comment: @Lazarus: To be pedantic: the magic with the square roots (once fixed) is already checking to see if the number is a Fibonacci number. That established, the loop is certain to terminate. While not defensively coded, that procedure is mathematically sound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the [`isDigit` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc4ksh8%28VS.71%29.aspx).

`isDigit` takes an ASCII character code and returns true if it represents a decimal digit.

You want to check whether the `double` returned by `sqrt` is an integer.

Comment: i tested isdigit() for a float and it dint worked so i thaught that if the sqrt of the number is a float then it will return 0 and i can accomlish my need from it

Comment: Well, you're wrong.  To check whether a number is an integer, you can write a function that casts it to `(int)` and checks whether it's equal to the original value.

Answer (score 3):

There's an obvious error in your use of `isdigit()`. That function (usually macro) is used to tell if a character is one of the characters `0`..`9` - certainly your code is dealing with numbers consistently and there's no need for character checking.

You'll want to take a closer look at what you're trying to accomplish. You're welcome to ask us which C functions might be suitable.

---

EDIT:

Ah, you want to know if that funky expression is an integer value. Alas, there's no built-in function for that. I haven't tested this, but I'd write

```
double a = (funky expr);
if (a == rint(a)) ...
```

... where `rint()` is a function that returns the `double` that's the nearest integer value to the given argument.

Comment: how do i find that if the number is square rooted is a int or a float?

Comment: The number returned from `sqrt` is *always* a `double`; the mathematical properties of the returned value don't change the datatype of the variable it's returned in. The question you need to ask is: "Is this number, which is held in a floating point double, equal to an integer, i.e is its fractional part 0?"

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `isdigit`? The result of sqrt is a `double` - you need to check that value directly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if `5 * num * num + 4` or `5 * num * num - 4` is a perfect square.  A function that will do this is:

```
int is_perfect_sq(double d)
{
    double sqroot = rint(sqrt(d));

    return (sqroot * sqroot) == d;
}
```

Note - this is a good disproof of the notion that you should *never* compare floating point numbers for equality.  In this case, it is fine, since a "perfect square" must be an integer.

Comment: hmmm and if one has to compare floats then comparing them by their address will be a good practise?